# flutter has a problem with redux dependencies

Tags: flutter, redux

i have a problem to run my flutter app, it seems flutter doesn't recognize it. i tried to connect to internet while running the project but the problem remains the same, here is the error message:

[image]

and here is the code where i inserted the dependency :

```
   dependencies:
    redux: ^4.0.0
    flutter_redux: ^0.6.0
```

Comment: In the future don't take screenshots of errors, paste them directly into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your package name is likely also `redux` according to [this Github issue.](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/181) You'll have to change your package name to something other than `redux` and you should be able to `flutter pub get`.

Comment: and which name can i use? it's a known package is it possible to change its name?

Comment: @RamsesKouam You can name it anything else that is not `redux` or another dependency name. Please upvote and accept if my answer helped you.

Comment: @RamsesKouam You're confusing the "package name" with the "dependency name". The package name is the name of YOUR project. The dependency name is `redux` or `flutter_redux`.

Answer (score -1):

this error was caused by the fact that i named my app REDUX, i changed it and it works now.